# What is the ideal length of a task on mobile?

Tags: user-behavior, mobile-application

I am designing an app that aims at enabling users to perform a complex task (sound editing) using a mobile device. I am trying to find information about the ideal length of a task on mobile, but it is hard for me to find recent surveys about how long users remain focused on mobile. Do you have by any chance  information about that? Thank you very much. Have a great week-end everyone!

Comment: Joanna, welcome to the site! But... what do you mean by ""mobile"? On the phone, in the metro? Or on the tablet, on your couch? Another important factor is the motivation of the user. To edit sounds for a video to upload in the next 5 seconds, or for a song to earn a living? More context badly needed!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the task because the expectations are different for different tasks.

People expect messaging or social media engagement tasks to be quick because they already are quick on messaging and social apps.

For stock trades, it’s conceptually a little more complicated and there are a series of decisions that have to be presented in sequence so it may take more time.

With mobile, UX design should still be reflective of the real world task whether it is complex or simple. Task speed expectations should reflect reality. I think the ergonomics just need to be approached a little differently due to display size and potential for use with one hand, gestures, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal length for a task on mobile is 0 seconds. I.e. ideally what you want is done already and automatically for you, saving you time and effort.

Comment: I thought about making a Comment to say this, but it was already here. Success!